# Let $G$ be a connected simple graph not having $P_4$ or $C_3$ as an induced subgraph Prove that $G$ is a biclique.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected simple graph not having $P_4$ or $C_3$ as an induced subgraph Prove that $G$ is a biclique.

I am looking for a proof that does not utilize induction.

Comment: This is not true. Consider any star.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream: A star is a biclique.

Comment: Oh right, my bad.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I found a proof :) what do you think?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream: I was buried in my own revision and only just saw this. It looks as if we came up with about the same idea, albeit from slightly different directions.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ has an odd cycle, let $C$ be one of minimal length $n$; clearly $n>3$. Let $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$ be consecutive vertices of $C$; $G$ contains no triangle, so these vertices induce either a $P_4$ or a $C_4$. The former case is excluded by hypothesis. In the latter case we can replace the path $v_1v_2v_3v_4$ in $C$ by the edge $v_1v_4$ to get a cycle of length $n-2$, contradicting the minimality of $n$. Thus, $G$ cannot have an odd cycle and therefore [must be bipartite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311665/proof-a-graph-is-bipartite-if-and-only-if-it-contains-no-odd-cycles).

Let the parts of $G$ be $V_0$ and $V_1$, and suppose that there are $v_0\in V_0$ and $v_1\in V_1$ that are not adjacent. $G$ is connected, so let $P$ be a path of minimal length from $v_0$ to $v_1$, say $u_1=v_0,u_2,\ldots,u_{2n}=v_1$, where $n\ge 2$. Minimality of $P$ and the hypothesis that $v_0$ is not adjacent to $v_1$ imply that $u_{2n-3}$ is not adjacent to $u_{2n}=v_1$, so $u_{2n-3},u_{2n-2},u_{2n-1}$, and $u_{2n}$ induce a copy of $P_4$. This is impossible, so $G$ must be a biclique.

---

Note that if we further require that $G$ not contain $P_4$ as a subgraph at all, we can show that $G$ is a star. Fix a vertex $v$ of maximal degree. If $\deg v=1$, $G$ is $K_{1,1}$. Otherwise, let $u$ and $w$ be distinct vertices adjacent to $v$. $G$ does not contain $C_3$, so $u$ and $w$ cannot be adjacent. Suppose that $u$ is adjacent to some vertex $x$ other than $v$; then $wvux$ is a copy of $P_4$, which is impossible. Thus, $G$ is a star with centre $v$.

Comment: Wow, look who the op of the question you linked is. Now I'm feeling nostalgic. Thanks for your incredible support over the years.

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream: I’m embarrassed: I was concentrating so hard on whether the answers there were usable that I didn’t even notice until you pointed it out! You’re very welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott according to this proposition,a Bipartite graph must not contain an induced subgraph of path $P_4$,that means an even length cycle must also not contain path $P_4$ as *induced subgraph*  but a Graph $G$ containg only cycle of length $6$ do contain induced subgraph $P_4$ ... i am confused !!!

Comment: @sourav: You’ve misunderstood the proposition. It says that a connected simple graph that does not contain an induced $P_4$ or $C_3$ must be a complete bipartite graph; it doesn’t say anything about bipartite graphs in general.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott a complete bipartite graph must be bipartite atleast ..!!! then how do a bipartite graph $C_6$ contains $P_4$ ..you can see the origin of my doubt here http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103x/pset7_sol.pdf

Comment: @sourav: The proposition only says something about graphs that do *not* contain induced $P_4$ or $C_3$. It doesn’t say anything about graphs, bipartite or not, that *do* contain one or both of these induced subgraphs.

Comment: ok that was my doubt ..thank you for clearing my doubt @BrianM.Scott sir

Comment: @sourav: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The girth of $G$ is $4$ or $\infty$. Suppose it is not. Then take the smallest cycle $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5\dots c_k$. Then the induced subgraph on $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ is not a $P_4$. So there is an edge between two non consecutive vertices. A contradiction since this creates a smaller cycle.

If the girth is $\infty$ $G$ has no cycles and no $P_4$, since it is connected it is a star.

If the girth is $4$, since it has no odd cycles it is bipartite, also notice both parts have at least two vertices.Assume it is not a biclique,take the shortest geodesic of even length in $G$ of length $4$ or more, call it $v_1,v_2\dots v_{2n}$. then $v_1,v_2,v_{2n-1},v_{2n}$ induces a $P_4$.