# How to prove that if G has no odd cycles then the chromatic number of G is 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

> $G$ has no odd cycles $\iff$ the $X(G)=2$

I already proved the reciprocal but I'm having trouble with this.

Here is my thinking:

> Let be $G=(V,E)$. If $G$ has no cycles, then $G$ is a tree so $X(G)=2$
>   since trees are bipartite.
>
> If $G$ has one cycle, I know it's an even cycle. Let be
>   $C_1=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ an even cycle of $G$. We can define
>   $k:C_1\rightarrow \{a,b\}$ a coloring of c.
>
> $k(v_1)=a, k(v_2)=b, ... , k(v_n)=b$
>
> Since $k=a$ for odd indexes, $k=b$ for even indexes, and $n$ is even.
>   So $X(C_1)=2$.

But I don't know how affirm that $X(G)=2$. Not to mention $G$ with more than one cycle.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no odd cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311665/proof-a-graph-is-bipartite-if-and-only-if-it-contains-no-odd-cycles) (Bipartite implies $X(G)\leq 2$ because you can color the left side red and the right side blue.) Note that a graph with no edges (like a completely disconnected graph or a graph with a single vertex) will have chromatic number $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if it $\chi(G) = 2$. Also, recall that a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles.

These two statements combined give our desired result.