# Let G be a connected graph with at least one cycle. Proof that G is biparthite when no cycle is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

So i have this task i am a little bit lost how to approach this problem.

Could anyone guide me trough it?

Let G be a connected graph with at least one cycle. Proof that G is bipartite when no cycle is odd.

Comment: Start with two empty sets $X$ and $Y$. Pick any vertex $v_0$ and put it in $X$. Then put in $X$ any vertex that is connected to $v_0$ by a path of even length and put in $Y$ those at an odd length. To see why this is a well defined function, observe that if a vertex is connected to $v_0$ by both a path of even and of odd lengths, then that would produce a cycle of odd length. Observe also that there cannot be edges between elements of $X$, since that would produce paths of odd length to $v_0$, and no edge between elements of $Y$ either.

Comment: Howdy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311665/proof-a-graph-is-bipartite-if-and-only-if-it-contains-no-odd-cycles